# How to combine props arithmetically in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, element-ui

I have a table that looks like this:

```
<el-table
:data="info"
class="myform"
stripe
style="width: 100%">
<el-table-column
  prop="location_name"
  label="Name"
  width="180">
</el-table-column>
<el-table-column
  v-if="promoActive"
  prop="original_price"
  label="Original Price"
  width="180">
</el-table-column>
<el-table-column
  prop="spaces_available"
  label="Spaces"
  width="180">
</el-table-column>
<el-table-column
  v-if="promoActive"
  prop="discount_value"
  label="Discount Value"
  width="180">
</el-table-column>
</el-table-column>
<el-table-column
  v-if="promoActive"
  label="Final Price"
  width="180">
</el-table-column>
</el-table>
```

I'm trying to make the prop value of the last table column equal to the the final price which is the original price minus the discount price. However, when I put the prop like this, it doesn't work:

```
<el-table-column
  v-if="promoActive"
  prop="(original_price - discount_value)"
  label="Final Price"
  width="180">
</el-table-column>
```

What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: You also can write a function here like `:prop: fnCalculate(your-obj-Here)`

Comment: `fnCalculate` must define in methods in component.

Comment: A quick fix will be to use `v-bind` on your prop, i.e. `v-bind:prop="(original_price - discount_value)"`. But as per my original answer, using a computed property is better because you abstract all these calculations away from the template

Answer (score 1):

you can use computed property like

```
    computed:{
       calculate(){
       return this.prop1 - this.prop2;
    }
 }
```

And then called the prop

Answer (score 0):

You can use computed property for this type of arithmetic calculations. where you can define a function and have full control over all properties of component.
follow this [link](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Basic-Example). you will get idea how you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered computed properties in Vue JS ?
refer : [https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties]

these properties are derived from the data and change whenever the source data is modified. This could be the recommended approach.

example :

```
computed:{
       finalPrize : function () {
                       return this.original_price - this.discount_value;
                     }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, the reason why your `prop="(original_price - discount_value)"` did not work is because `prop` attribute is evaluated as text unless you use the `v-bind` syntax. So this should work:

```
v-bind:prop="(original_price - discount_value)"
```

However, this is what [computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) in VueJS can be used for, to abstract all these calculation logic away from your template: you can perform the calculations in there, and simply use the [`v-bind` directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) to bind the computed value to the element. Let's name your computed property `finalPrice`. In your VueJS app/component code, you can do this:

```
computed: {
    finalPrice() {
        return this.original_price - this.discount_value;
    }
}
```

Then, update your markup to use `v-bind:prop="finalPrice"`:

```
<el-table-column
  v-if="promoActive"
  v-bind:prop="finalPrice"
  label="Final Price"
  width="180">
</el-table-column>
```

p/s: If you prefer to use shorthands, fret not: `:prop="finalPrice"` (note the `:` prefix) is syntactically identical to `v-bind:prop="finalPrice"`.

---

Not recommended, but still workable: if you want to pass the arguments to perform calculations instead, you can use a method instead:

```
method: {
    calculateFinalPrice(original, discount) {
        return original- discount;
    }
}
```

And your markup will be:

```
<el-table-column
  v-if="promoActive"
  v-bind:prop="calculateFinalPrice(original_price, discount_value)"
  label="Final Price"
  width="180">
</el-table-column>
```

Comment: But how do I do this so when I loop through the array of data being printed to the table, it knows which original price/discount price to use for each final price?

Comment: There's more than one result so I must need to pass the index to the computed property right? But it doesn't take any arguments

Comment: @IsaacHerring Can you update your question to include that? It is not obvious from your question that you're using it in a for loop.